# "Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null" y "BSN is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, modal

Este código me funciona perfectamente en una página de prueba, pero cuando lo añado a la página web que estoy creando, entonces me lanza dos errores en la consola, los cuales son:

> Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

> BSN is not defined

**Nota:**

No necesita CDN de JQuery en la versión 5 de Bootstrat.

En el sitio de prueba tengo todo ordenado así:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
     <style>
        Estilos CSS
     </style>
  <body>
     Codigo HTML
  </body>
     Archivo js 1
     Archivo js 2
 </html>
```

He aquí el link hacia el codepen, ya que se sobrepasó el limite de caracteres aquí:

https://codepen.io/starlin-batista/pen/QWGbdWv

Comment: Agrega un [example], viendo el pen, no necesitas poner acá todo el JavaScript que incluye la librería, sólo su CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, ya pude dar con el problema.

Les explico:

Uso PHP y tengo varios archivos por separados que conforman la pagina web, tales como un
**header.php**,
**menuizquierdo.php**,
**seccionprincipal.php**,
Ect.

Todo eso lo llamo mediante la función *include("")*.

No pongo código en esta respuesta, ya que no era problema de código, sino de saber organizar los archivos en la sección correspondiente(**seccionprincipal.php**).